# SkiaSharp displays svg file in black color in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, svg, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am using nuget packages

- SkiaSharp.Svg
- SkiaSharp.Views.Forms
- SkiaSharp.Extended

The problem is some SVG files display fine, but others show me all black and I have no idea why that is, If you could help me please I would be very grateful

This is a helper class to render the SVG files:

```
public class SVGImage : ContentView
{
    // Bindable property to set the SVG image path
    public static readonly BindableProperty SourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
      nameof(Source), typeof(string), typeof(SVGImage), default(string), propertyChanged: RedrawCanvas);

    private readonly SKCanvasView canvasView = new SKCanvasView();

    public SVGImage()
    {
        this.Padding = new Thickness(0);
        this.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
        this.Content = this.canvasView;
        this.canvasView.PaintSurface += this.CanvasView_PaintSurface;
    }

    // Property to set the SVG image path
    public string Source
    {
        get => (string)this.GetValue(SourceProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to invaldate the canvas to update the image
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bindable">The target canvas</param>
    /// <param name="oldValue">Previous state</param>
    /// <param name="newValue">Updated state</param>
    public static void RedrawCanvas(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        SVGImage image = bindable as SVGImage;
        image?.canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method update the canvas area with teh image
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender</param>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments</param>
    private void CanvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKCanvas canvas = args.Surface.Canvas;
        canvas.Clear();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Source))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Get the assembly information to access the local image
        Assembly assembly = typeof(SVGImage).Assembly;

        // Update the canvas with the SVG image
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(assembly.GetName().Name + ".Images." + this.Source))
        {
            SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg svg = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
            svg.Load(stream);
            SKImageInfo imageInfo = args.Info;
            canvas.Translate(imageInfo.Width / 2f, imageInfo.Height / 2f);
            SKRect rectBounds = svg.ViewBox;
            float xRatio = imageInfo.Width / rectBounds.Width;
            float yRatio = imageInfo.Height / rectBounds.Height;
            float minRatio = Math.Min(xRatio, yRatio);
            canvas.Scale(minRatio);
            canvas.Translate(-rectBounds.MidX, -rectBounds.MidY);
            canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture);
        }
    }
}
```

showing the svg image in the xaml

```
<StackLayout>
    <local:SVGImage
        HeightRequest="100"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Source="Placa.svg"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        WidthRequest="100" />
</StackLayout>
```

as seen in the image the svg file is shown in black without the colors

[image: svg black]

When should i show this way

Placa.svg:

[image: svg origin]

**UPDATE**

The Svg file

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 120 70.15">
    <defs>
        <style>.d{fill:#fff;}.e{fill:#c1c3c8;}.f{fill:#464655;}.g{fill:#ff6e40;}.h{isolation:isolate;opacity:.1;}</style>
    </defs>
    <g id="a"/>
    <g id="b">
        <g id="c">
            <g>
                <path class="e" d="M107.62,0H12.38C5.54,0,0,5.54,0,12.38V57.77c0,6.83,5.54,12.38,12.38,12.38H107.62c6.84,0,12.38-5.54,12.38-12.38V12.38c0-6.84-5.54-12.38-12.38-12.38Z"/>
                <path class="d" d="M12.38,61.29c-1.94,0-3.52-1.58-3.52-3.52V12.38c0-1.94,1.58-3.52,3.52-3.52H107.62c1.94,0,3.52,1.58,3.52,3.52V57.77c0,1.94-1.58,3.52-3.52,3.52H12.38Z"/>
                <g>
                    <path class="g" d="M107.62,8.86H12.38c-1.94,0-3.52,1.58-3.52,3.52v9.13H111.14V12.38c0-1.94-1.58-3.52-3.52-3.52Z"/>
                    <path class="g" d="M8.86,48.64v9.13c0,1.94,1.58,3.52,3.52,3.52H107.62c1.94,0,3.52-1.58,3.52-3.52v-9.13H8.86Z"/>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <path class="f" d="M29.28,13.13c1.15,0,2.08,.93,2.08,2.08s-.93,2.08-2.08,2.08-2.08-.93-2.08-2.08,.93-2.08,2.08-2.08Z"/>
                    <path class="f" d="M29.28,52.9c1.15,0,2.08,.93,2.08,2.08s-.93,2.08-2.08,2.08-2.08-.93-2.08-2.08,.93-2.08,2.08-2.08Z"/>
                    <path class="f" d="M90.72,13.13c1.15,0,2.08,.93,2.08,2.08s-.93,2.08-2.08,2.08-2.08-.93-2.08-2.08,.93-2.08,2.08-2.08Z"/>
                    <path class="f" d="M90.72,52.9c1.15,0,2.08,.93,2.08,2.08s-.93,2.08-2.08,2.08-2.08-.93-2.08-2.08,.93-2.08,2.08-2.08Z"/>
                </g>
                <path class="h" d="M19.99,57.77V12.38c0-6.84,5.54-12.38,12.38-12.38H12.38C5.54,0,0,5.54,0,12.38V57.77c0,6.83,5.54,12.38,12.38,12.38h19.99c-6.84,0-12.38-5.54-12.38-12.38Z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can view a .svg file in any text editor. (Temporarily add ".txt" at end of file name, if you have trouble loading it into the text editor.) Please open the "black" .svg file in text editor, copy the text inside the file, and paste it into your question.

Comment: updated question please can you check

Comment: Hmm. Nothing wrong with that SVG. Seems like you've encountered some bug or limitation in SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg's SVG support. If no one has any suggestion, file an issue at [github SkiaSharp.Extended issues](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp.Extended/issues). I don't think its specifically a Xamarin.Forms issue (though I could be wrong).

Comment: If you make a public github repo to demonstrate this problem, add it to that issue, and add a link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a known issue and is discussed here:

https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp.Extended/issues/48